# Como adicionar lista a um objeto JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou a algum tempo fazendo diversos testes para conseguir adicionar uma lista a um objeto. Tentei de diversas formas e deixei o código neste formato para que fique mais fácil a compreensão do problema!

O código abaixo me retorna um objeto deste tipo: `{nome: "matheus", produto: "caderno", values: {qtd: "7",valor1: "2.22",valor2: "2.22",valor3: "22.22"}}`. Passando somente o ultimo objeto criado na variável intermediaria gostaria que ele me retornasse um objeto com a lista no values neste formato:

```
{nome: "matheus", produto: "caderno", values: 
[{qtd: "4",valor1: "1.00",valor2: "1.20",valor3: "11.20"},
{qtd: "5","valor1": "1.20",valor2: "1.03",valor3: "21.03"},
{qtd: "6",valor1: "1.22",valor2: "1.12",valor3: "2.22"},
{qtd: "7",valor1: "2.22",valor2: "2.22",valor3: "22.22"},
]}
```

Tentei adicionar com o push não deu certo, tentei colocar uma lista no objeto e não deu, fiz vários testes e nada deu certo segue abaixo o código:

```js
var object = new Object();

object.nome = "matheus";

object.produto= "caderno"

teste();
function teste() {

    let listQtd = ["4","5","6","7"]
    let listValor1 = ["1.00","1.20","1.22","2.22"]
    let listValor2 = ["1.20","1.03","1.12","2.22"]
    let listValor3 = ["11.20","21.03","31.12","22.22"]  

    let retList = new Object();

    for (let i = 0; i < listQtd.length; i++) {
        retList.qtd = listQtd[i];
        retList.valor1 = listValor1[i];
        retList.valor2 = listValor2[i];
        retList.valor3 = listValor3[i]

        // Aqui ele so adiciona o ultimo elemento preciso que adicione uma lista.
        object.values = retList
    }

    console.log(object)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta inicializar o valor do campo `values` com um `array` vazio e utilizar a função `push` para incrementá-lo.

```js
var object = new Object();

object.nome = "matheus";
object.produto = "caderno"
object.values = [];

teste();

function teste() {

  let listQtd = ["4", "5", "6", "7"]
  let listValor1 = ["1.00", "1.20", "1.22", "2.22"]
  let listValor2 = ["1.20", "1.03", "1.12", "2.22"]
  let listValor3 = ["11.20", "21.03", "31.12", "22.22"]

  for (let i = 0; i < listQtd.length; i++) {
    let retList = new Object();
    retList.qtd = listQtd[i];
    retList.valor1 = listValor1[i];
    retList.valor2 = listValor2[i];
    retList.valor3 = listValor3[i];

    object.values.push(retList);
  }

  console.log(object)
}
```

O operador `=` é de atribuição e não incremental, por isso sua solução anterior não funcionava da maneira que você desejava.

Comment: A solução atende muito obrigado!